# General questions on the eigenfunctions of Laplacian and Dirac operators

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, laplacian, spin-geometry

We know that the eigenvalues of the Laplacian contains a lot of information of a Riemannian manifold, but they do not determine the full information ( [Hearing the shape of a drum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum)). And the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian seem to have much more information ([see the reference](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/toth/spectral%20geometry.pdf)). Now my question is that whether the eigenfunctions of the Dirac operator would contain more information than that of Laplacian, since it seems to me that the Dirac operator is a more refined version of the Laplacian ( a Riemmanian manifold could have several spin structure).
Here the Laplacian means the Laplace-Beltrami operator and the Dirac operator means the Dirac operator on the spinor bundle. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you can even formulate the eigenfunctions of an operator on a manifold without already more or less knowing the manifold. Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: ok, let's assume the manifold is given.